# Internal IP not localhost?

Tags: ip, localhost

Recently I've had this problem with a Tomcat server and it was saying that it couldn't resolve the host address. It turned out to be that it required my internal IP to be assigned to localhost, i.e. 192.168.A.B but why was it not already resolved as localhost? And there's no good adding that IP to my hosts file because as soon as I change network it'll become something else.

Comment: localhost typically resovles to 127.0.0.1, the loopback address. That IP will always resolve to your local machine. Perhaps providing the relevant sections of your Tomcat config would help.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what "this problem" actually is!!!